# Should I create a completely new instance for high write in large volumes?

Tags: mongodb, latency

I currently have a collection that collects real-time sensor data, so each sensor is ingesting a value every 5-10 seconds and I have about 50 sensors. I also have collections for user data, etc. Currently, I am batch updating my sensor data `insertMany` every 1000 documents. However, it still bottlenecks the db affecting the regular lookups in other collections. My read latency goes through the roof. One option I am thinking of is creating a new instance just for ingesting sensor data so it doesn't impact user data speeds. Is this the right direction?

Comment: You insert a few documents per second - that's nothing! Most likely the problem is caused somewhere else.

Comment: I don't think so, as soon as I comment out that insert line the issue goes away

Comment: But I don't think it is the amount of data, as I said that's nothing. Design failure seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: On an infrastructure/design side, any ideas on where I should start looking? Are there collected metrics I can use to find the core issue?